# InnoDB erratic performance

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm doing some tests with a really simple InnoDB table (named Test) with the following structure:

```
Id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
UserId int(10) NOT NULL
Body varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
CreatedAt datetime NOT NULL
```

one additional index on UserId:

```
KEY Idx_Test_UserId (UserId) USING BTREE
```

When I try to execute this query...

```
INSERT INTO Comments (UserId,Body,CreatedAt) VALUES (1,'This is a test',NOW())
```

...sometimes I get the operation completed in a few milliseconds but some other times it takes around a second.

I have the same issue with a simple SELECT statement:

```
SELECT Body FROM Comments WHERE UserId=1
```

I'm the only one person doing the tests on this specific table, I really don't understand I have such execution time differences.

Last note, when I'm doing the same tests with a MyISAM table I don't have any issues.

Comment: You say that you're the only one doing test on this table but what about the rest of the database/server?  Seems like this may have something to do with server load and database engine load.

Comment: My database is on my local machine (without any load) and I'm the only one person to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For InnoDB, the "auto_increment" variable should be in an index (first or alone) to avoid some lock issues. This doesn't happen with MyISAM, as far as I understand.

By the way, why isn't "Id" the primary key? Not that it's necessary but it just "looks" like it should be for this table.